# css specificity for an active tag in a menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML, which is output by a plugin, so I can't change some of the output:

```
    <div id="submenu">
        <h2>text</h2>
<!-- can't change start -->
       <ul class="nav secondary">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About You</a></li>
        </ul>
<!--cant' change end-->
    </div>
```

Specifically I have no control over the UL class names that get output (nav an secondary), the  li tags (active class is the issue) and the a tag.

The problem is I can't figure out how to get the  li.active to change the font color of the a tag for the active link.  Here is my css:

```
#submenu {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 53px;
     margin: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
     padding: 5px 0px 2px 0px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
#submenu h2 {
}
#submenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
#submenu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 0px 0px 28px;
    display: inline;
}
#submenu li a {
    color: #333333;
}
#submenu a:hover {
    color: #A0A0A0;
}

#submenu a {
    padding:0px;
}
#submenu .active {
    color:#CC0000; /**#A0A0A0; */
}
#submenu .nav > li > a:hover {
    padding:0px;
    background:none;
}
```

The specificity is confusing me.  How do I get li.active to override the font color of the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with specificity.

`#submenu li a` matches the `a` element but `#submenu .active` matches the `li` element.

Nothing ever sets the `a` to `color: inherit` so it will never take the colour from the `li` element.

Change the selector to match the `a` instead of the `li`:

```
#submenu li.active a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to something like:

```
li.active a { color: #CC0000; }
```

It should override the standard `a` color

For more information on specificity in CSS, take a look at this:

http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/

I have that goofy graphic printed out and hanging on my cubicle wall.  It's quite helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried making sure that your css is being loaded after the css generated or used by the plugin?